# Culmulative Sum in pandas of unindexed data by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have a situation where I am trying to sum  values in a large data set based on several criteria.

I have managed to achieve this using a nested loop with another script, but was hoping that using Pandas might be easier.

my data set looks like this.

```
date         regionNo    sales
2020-04-15   1           2
2020-04-14   1           3
2020-04-15   2           3
2020-04-14   2           1
```

I want to add a column that indicates the cumulative sales in a region to that particular date.

The conditionals would be something like:

```
salesSum = sum(['sales'] where ['date'] <= "*row date*" and ['region'] == "*row region*")
```

Apologies for the above code. It is sort of python-y pseudo code.

The problem is that I don't know how to reference a value in the table. Like a cell reference in excel.

Is this possible in pandas?

I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
date         regionNo    sales  salesSum
2020-04-15   1           2      5
2020-04-14   1           3      3
2020-04-15   2           3      4
2020-04-14   2           1      1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered sorting by [`"regionNo"`, `"date"`] and then iterating through the rows to calculate the cumulative sum per region?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of referencing back is usually done by window functions.  However in your case you have a dependence on the value of the `date` column.  So a fixed window will not work.  What you can do is use `DataFrame.groupby.apply` where you group by "regionNo".  Note, that doing this is slow and not recommended.  But unfortunately, I don't know of any other way of achieving this kind of "conditional aggregation".